# Swift: Get HTTP code from Server Response

Tags: php, swift, http-status-codes

I'm using the following function in Swift to connect to a PHP Script on a server and then process my request:

```
func pushtoserveronclick() {
    var URL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://someurl.com/")!
    var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:URL)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    var bodyData = "data=something&version=\(appVersion)"
    request.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
        {
            (response, data, error) in                       
            println(response)                
    }
 }
```

When I run the app I get this returned as the response:

```
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x14e53170> { URL: http://someurl.com/ } { status code: 200, headers {
Connection = "Keep-Alive";
"Content-Type" = "text/html";
Date = "Fri, 05 Dec 2014 06:23:23 GMT";
"Keep-Alive" = "timeout=2, max=100";
Server = Apache;
"Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
```

How would I get the **status code** that is being returned so I can perform a check on it and tell whether or not it's a connection issue?

Comment: @mattt Already tried that. I get 'NSURLResponse' does not have a member named 'statusCode'

Comment: Cast it to `NSHTTPURLResponse` first. `[(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode]`

Comment: @mattt is that not Obj-C ? I'm pretty new to this

Comment: Sorry, forgot the context of the question. See answer.

Answer (score 2):

`NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest` uses `NSURLResponse` in the type signature, but as long as you're connecting over HTTP, the instance is (usually) `NSHTTPURLResponse`, which has the `statusCode`.

You can check and cast it this way:

```
if let HTTPResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
    let statusCode = HTTPResponse.statusCode
}
```